# From preterite to perfect—sentences containing modal verbs and "weil"

Tags: modal-verb, perfect-tense, preterite

I want to convert these two sentences from *preterite* into *perfect*.

> 1) Meine Frau und ich wollten Geschenke für meine Familie in Brasilien kaufen.
>
> 2) Weil ich ein bestimmtes Buch nicht finden konnte, ging ich zur Information.

For 1) I searched and found a [posting](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28141/using-modal-verbs-with-the-perfekt-tense). Then I wrote this; but I'm not sure if it is correct:

> Meine Frau und ich wollen Geschenke für meine Familie in Brasilien gekauft haben.

For 2) I searched and pondered; but I gave up. I'll appreciate if someone could explain to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples need to use a tool that is called *Ersatzinfinitiv* (Substitute infinitive). This is used when you actually want to form the participle of a modal verb or some special verbs like *brauchen, heißen, lassen, sehen, hören, fühlen, helfen*, and the sentence already uses an infinitive construction (in your examples "kaufen" and "finden"). The participle of the modal verb is then substituted by an infinitive.

What you want to build would look like (if you strictly follow the rules of forming perfect tense)

> <s>Meine Frau und ich haben Geschenke für meine Familie in Brasilien kaufen gewollt</s>.

and

> <s>Weil ich ein bestimmtes Buch nicht habe finden gekonnt, bin ich zur Information gegangen</s>.

Which are, unfortunately, wrong. The tool is that the participle of the modal verb needs to be replaced by its infinitive - Your sentences should end up like

> Meine Frau und ich haben Geschenke für meine Familie in Brasilien kaufen wollen.
>
> Weil ich ein bestimmtes Buch nicht habe finden können, bin ich zur Information gegangen.

Answer (score 1):

Tofro's answer is correct. In addition, your sentence

> Meine Frau und ich wollen Geschenke für meine Familie in Brasilien gekauft haben.

is grammatically correct, but it means a different thing:

*My wife and I **pretend** to have bought presents for my family in Brazil.*

That is because the *will … haben* and *will … sein* have this additional special meaning.